# Can't connect to NoMachine NX Server. Using Remmina

Tags: ubuntu, nx, archbang, remmina

## My Setup

### Client

- Ubuntu OS

  - Remmina Remote Desktop Client + remmina-plugin-nx

### Server

- Arch Bang OS

  - NoMachine for Linux - x86_64

    - Chose fedora system for install

## My Userlist

```
[folatt@ArkOS_Dev log]$ sudo /usr/NX/bin/nxserver --userlist
NX> 149 NX users list

Username                         Redirected to                  Trusted for 
-------------------------------- ------------------------------ -----------------
folatt
```

## NX Server app

[image: NX Server]

## NX Client app

[image: Remmina]

/usr/NX/var/log/nxerror.log

```
Info: Handler started with pid 25064 on Sat May 14 17:34:12 2016.
Info: Handling connection from 192.168.178.53 port 52378 on Sat May 14 17:34:12 2016.
25064 25078 17:34:20 989.611 DaemonGreeter/DaemonGreeter: WARNING! Read from FD#5 failed.
25064 25078 17:34:20 989.836 DaemonGreeter/DaemonGreeter: WARNING! Error 5, 'Input/output error'.
Warning: Connection from 192.168.178.53 port 52378 failed on Sat May 14 17:34:20 2016.
Warning: Connection error is 5, 'Input/output error'.
Info: Handler with pid 25064 terminated on Sat May 14 17:34:20 2016.
```